# How to fix textbox position and add scroll functionality to messages

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am writing a chat application with React. The current design of the Messenger component has a left-sidebar, a central block and a right-sidebar. Ideally, the bottom of the central block is a fixed sized textbox and the rest of the space from the top to the block to the top of the textbox is an area for messages, which allows for scrolling when overflow.

However, I’m not sure how to add that “scrolling” and fixed size textbox functionality to my application. Currently the start of the textbox trails after the last message, and when the last message exceeds the vertical screen size, the textbox is not visible.

Can someone suggest how to do this? Here’s my react code with just the essential elements, and the `App.css`. Feel free to ask for more code if needed.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import classNames from "classnames";
import "./App.css";

// Components
import _ from "lodash";

const MESSENGER_HEIGHT = "height";
const MESSENGER_NEW_MESSAGE = "newMessage";
const MESSENGER_SEARCH_USER = "searchUser";
const MESSENGER_SHOW_SEARCH_USER = "showSearchUser";
const MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";
const MESSENGER_MEMBERS = "members";
const MESSENGER_MESSAGES = "messages";
const MESSENGER_CHANNELS = "channels";
const MESSENGER_PROFILE_ID = "profile_id";

//remove the authentication routes



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    const locals = this.state;
    locals[MESSENGER_HEIGHT] = window.innerHeight;
    locals[MESSENGER_NEW_MESSAGE] = "";
    locals[MESSENGER_SEARCH_USER] = "";
    locals[MESSENGER_SHOW_SEARCH_USER] = false;
    locals[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID] = "Mk3d9WJRiyifxgtJ1Ep1"; //TODO: trial run set default one
    locals[MESSENGER_MEMBERS] = ["person1", "person2"];
    locals[MESSENGER_MESSAGES] = [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "10",
      "11",
      "12",
      "13"
    ];
    locals[MESSENGER_CHANNELS] = [];
    locals[MESSENGER_PROFILE_ID] = "Testing profile_id";
  }

  render() {
    let component_variable = null;
    let members_list;
    //About the presence system
    if (this.state.members.length > 0) {
      members_list = (
        <div>
          <h2 className="title">Members</h2>
          <div className="members">
            {this.state.members.map(member => {
              return (
                <div className="member">
                  <div className="member-info">
                    <h2> {member}</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      members_list = null;
    }

    let search_bar = null;

    let messages_list;
    if (this.state.messages !== undefined) {
      messages_list = (
        <div>
          <div ref={ref => (this.messagesRef = ref)} className="messages">
            {this.state.messages.map(message => {
              return (
                <div className={classNames("message", { me: true })}>
                  <div className="message-body">
                    <div className="message-author">{"You "} says:</div>
                    <div className="message-text">
                      {`Testing message ${message}`}
                    </div>
                    <div className="message-timestamp">Some Date</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      messages_list = null;
    }

    let text_box;

    if (this.state.members.length > 0) {
      text_box = (
        <div className="messenger-input">
          <div className="text-input">
            <textarea
              onKeyUp={this.handle_textbox_keyup}
              onChange={this.handle_textbox_set_state}
              value={this.state["newMessage"]}
              placeholder="Write your message..."
            />
          </div>
          <div className="actions">
            <button onClick={() => this.handleSend()} className="send">
              Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      text_box = null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="app-messenger">
        <div className="header">
          <div className="left">
            <button className="left-action">
              <i className="icon-settings-streamline-1" />
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={this.handle_create_channel}
              className="right-action"
            >
              <i className="icon-edit-modify-streamline" />
            </button>
            <h2>Messenger</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="content" />
          <div className="right">Hello world</div>
        </div>

        <div className="main">
          <div className="sidebar-left">
            <div className="chanels">
              {this.state.channels.map((channel, key) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    onClick={key => {
                      this.props.select_or_create_message_room({
                        id: channel._id
                      });
                    }}
                    key={channel._id}
                    className={classNames("chanel", {
                      notify: _.get(channel, "notify") === true
                    })}
                  >
                    <div className="channel-id">
                      {channel[MESSENGER_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_ID]}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="content">
            {messages_list},{text_box}
          </div>

          {/*TODO: Member list*/}
          <div className="sidebar-right">{members_list}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
html,
  /*body {*/
  /*  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',*/
  /*    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',*/
  /*    sans-serif;*/
  /*  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);*/
  /*}*/

.container {
  margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /*Cannot hidden bc the home screen is ugly*/
}
.nav-container {
  margin: auto;
}
.nav-container svg {
  color: #fff;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}



body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; }

.app-messenger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.app-messenger .header {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
.app-messenger .header .left {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; }
.app-messenger .header .left .left-action {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 0; }
.app-messenger .header .left .right-action {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 0; }
.app-messenger .header .left h2 {
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
.app-messenger .header .left button {
  background: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 0 none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer; }
.app-messenger .header .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.app-messenger .header .content h2 {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center; }
.app-messenger .header .right {
  width: 300px; }
.app-messenger .header .right .user-bar {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 10px; }
.app-messenger .header .right .user-bar .profile-name {
  padding-right: 10px; }
.app-messenger .header .right .user-bar .profile-image {
  line-height: 50px; }
.app-messenger .header .right .user-bar .profile-image img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0; }
.app-messenger .main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; }
.app-messenger .main .sidebar-left {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
.app-messenger .main .sidebar-right {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 300px; }
.app-messenger .main .sidebar-right .title {
  padding: 10px; }
.app-messenger .main .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; }
.app-messenger .main .content .messages {
  flex-grow: 1; }
.app-messenger .main .content .messenger-input {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.app-messenger .main .content .messenger-input .text-input {
  flex-grow: 1; }
.app-messenger .main .content .messenger-input .text-input textarea {
  border: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 15px; }
.app-messenger .main .content .messenger-input .actions button.send {
  background: #2ecc71;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  line-height: 50px; }

.messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%; }
.messages .message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 15px; }
.messages .message .message-user-image img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%; }
.messages .message .message-body {
  padding-left: 10px; }

/*Try adding it manually, by right should make a message card, but will lose colour */

.messages .message .message-body .message-text {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px; }


.messages .message.me {
  justify-content: flex-end; }
.messages .message.me .message-body .message-text {
  background: #2ecc71;
  color: #FFF; }

.chanels {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%; }
.chanels .chanel {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 8px; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image {
  width: 30px; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image img {
  max-width: 100%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-2 img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-2 img:first-child {
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-3 img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-3 img:first-child {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-3 img:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-4 img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-4 img:first-child {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-4 img:nth-child(3n) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%; }
.chanels .chanel .user-image .channel-avatars.channel-avatars-4 img:last-child {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 15px; }
.chanels .chanel .chanel-info {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  overflow: hidden; }
.chanels .chanel .chanel-info h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; }
.chanels .chanel .chanel-info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; }
.chanels .chanel.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
.chanels .chanel.notify .chanel-info p {
  color: #2ecc71; }

.members .member {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 8px; }

.members .member .member-info {
  padding-left: 8px;
  flex-grow: 1; }
.members .member .member-info h2 {
  font-size: 14px; }
.members .member .member-info p {
  font-size: 12px; }

h2.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }


.app-message {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
.app-message.error {
  background: #e74c3c;
  color: #FFF;
  border-color: #e74c3c; }


/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

A runnable version is also available on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/affectionate-dewdney-kkzc2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Can you please provide a simple self contained question? Putting it in codesandbox would help

Comment: please post only relevant code, there is far too much here. we don't need to see everything

Comment: Try to paste only relevant code, pasting the whole file here makes no sense and also less attractive people to answer as they have to read unnecessary code.

Or try to paste it on code sandbox/

Comment: I have removed some of the irrelevant code to the problem. I have never used code sandbox before, so I may need to pick it up before I post the link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `max-height` on `.messages`:

```
.messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```